# Counting number of events on each date in a dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas

I'm attempting to count the number of events that occur on each date that occurs in the data frame. I have created a new dataframe with the dates occurring only once, how would i go about counting and totalling up the events that happen on each date.

I so far haven't been able to find a suitable method of doing so.

This is an example of the data I have:

```
date    event
01/01/10    1
01/01/10    1
01/01/10    2
02/01/10    1
04/01/10    3
```

I am hoping to get this results

```
date     event1 event2  event3
01/01/10    2     1      0
02/01/10    1     0      0
04/01/10    0     0      1
```

Any suggestions will be welcomed gratefully

Comment: Make your question clearer with input and expected output

Comment: Thanks Ankit Agrawal, just for future reference, how would i go about setting up the question with the tables you kindly edited in?

Comment: You're welcome! Just mark them as a code block

Comment: Thanks again, Ankit.

Comment: Copy paste the table in the question, select the text and click on `{}`. You can consult the help button (the ?) in the right corner of the tool bar on top of the textarea where you write question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `pd.crosstab`:

```
pd.crosstab(df['date'], df['event'])
```

Output:

```
event      date  1  2  3
0      01/01/10  2  1  0
1      02/01/10  1  0  0
2      04/01/10  0  0  1
```

And, we can do some cleanup and renaming like this:

```
pd.crosstab(df['date'], df['event'])\
  .add_prefix('event')\
  .rename_axis(None, axis=1)\
  .reset_index()
```

Output:

```
       date  event1  event2  event3
0  01/01/10       2       1       0
1  02/01/10       1       0       0
2  04/01/10       0       0       1
```